# how to find the domain of a function like this and graph it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

\begin{equation} f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 7}{\sqrt{(\frac{x+2}{4})^{x^2} – (\frac{x+2}{4})^{2|x|+3}}} \end{equation}

I tried to get the domain by finding where the denominator is bigger than zero
since at zero it is undefinable  where its  positive {the denominator) since the square root sign
\begin{equation} {(\frac{x+2}{4})^{x^2} – (\frac{x+2}{4})^{2|x|+3}}> 0 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} {(\frac{x+2}{4})^{x^2} > (\frac{x+2}{4})^{2|x|+3}} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} {{x^2} > {2|x|+3}} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} {{x^2} -{2|x|-3}>0} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} { where \ for \ the \ equation  }{\ \ \ }{ { x^2} -{2x-3}=0}  {\ the \ solutions    \ are}\end{equation}
\begin{equation} {(x-3)(x+1)}  \end{equation}
\begin{equation} {(x=3)(x=-1)}  \end{equation}

\begin{equation} {{x^2} -{2|x|-3}=0} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} {here \ I \ deduced \ that \ we \ only \ take \ when \ x >=0 \ for this equation  \ because \ of the \  square \  and \  || \ sign }\end{equation}
\begin{equation} {{x^2} -{2|x|-3}>0} \end{equation}
so we get  the following  domain for the Inequality (3,∞)

\begin{equation} {(\frac{x+2}{4})^{x^2} – (\frac{x+2}{4})^{2|x|+3}}= 0 \end{equation}
when ? when there is 1 to the power of a number - 1 to the power of a number
or when we have ${0 - 0 }$
so
\begin{equation} {(\frac{x+2}{4})}= 0 \end{equation}
x=-2
\begin{equation} {(\frac{x+2}{4})}= 1 \end{equation}
x=2
and we can see that the numbers between them are eligible when Substituting
but still not sure how to take the whole period  (-2,2)  as part of  the domain

any tips and explanations and corrections would help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the points (-2,0) and (2,1) the base of the power is in (0,1).

The exponents have $x^2<1$ , while $2|x|+3 >1$.

It follows that the first term is greater than the second, because
$$  \forall \ (x,p,q),\quad  0<(x,p)<1, q>1  \quad x^p>x,\quad x^q<x$$.